# Bash: Iterate through variables showing variable name and value

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get a list of specific variables and then the values of those variables?

```
#!/bin/bash

varA=1.3.5                # need this
varB=2.4.6                # need this
varC=3.6.9                # need this
ignoreA="Do not need"
ignoreB="Or this"

vars=`compgen -A variable | grep var`

for v in ${vars} ; do
  echo "${p} = $${p}"
done
```

I get the list of the variables, but can't work out how to get the value of each of those variables in the for-loop?  I've tried a number of different combinations but can't wrap my head around what this should be:

- ${$p}
- {$$p}
- $(${p})

Comment: See in particular [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). Usually, it's better practice to keep any arbitrary names in an associative array; but you can absolutely loop over names having a prefix without one as well, and both that FAQ and the linked duplicate describe how to do so.

Comment: `for item in ${string}`, btw, is generally a code smell and best avoided. If you want to track a list of things you can index into, iterate over, etc., use an array rather than a string for storing it. The caveats in [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) apply; so does [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). And in determining how to populate that array, be wary of [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29).